# Is a question on title of a movie on topic?

Tags: discussion

Here is a sample question that I might want to ask:

> In the movie 10 things I hate about you, I found no hint, why is the name of the movie is so? There is nothing related to "hate" in the movie. In fact it is a love-story. So why is the name so? Am I missing something?

Or,

> Does the name of the movie "Fracture" sound related to the movie in anyway? How come the word "Fracture" relates to the movie?

Are these types of question allowed here?

Comment: As Tyler says they are on-topic and doesn't have any issue in your examples. Similar questions i have even asked here http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3220/what-is-the-significance-of-3dd-in-pirahana-3dd & http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2192/what-does-book-of-shadows-stands-for-in-title-of-movie-blair-witch-2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These types of questions can be on-topic as it is usually a good way of analyzing a piece by finding out why the title was chosen.

Now, there is a point where this adds no value to the appreciation to the movie when we're talking easily figured out names like **Beethoven 6: Electric Dog Parade** where the title clearly dictates its about Beethoven and his Electric Dog Parade.

Its another case of a question where you have to ask yourself "Well, is this too easy, or does this title really need analyzing on why it was chosen?"

---

For your specific examples, I don't see an issue myself with them.

Comment: Of course, we expect askers to ask question which is really worth asking, otherwise they will surely be closed!